# Quotienting a mutually recursive family of datatypes

Tags: isabelle

Is it possible to quotient a family of mutually recursive datatypes in Isabelle/HOL using the `quotient_type` mechanism with a family of equivalence relations?

If so, is there a good example of this somewhere already?  Searching the Isabelle documentation, and the paper describing the revamped `quotient_type` mechanism, doesn't prove very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `quotient_type` can handle only one type at a time. If you want to do a quotient over several mutual types, you must do the encoding and decoding manually, but this is pretty simple.

Suppose your two types are `t1` and `t2` with the equivalence relations `r1 :: t1 => t1 => bool` and `r2 :: t2 => t2 => bool`. Then,

```
quotient_type q = "t1 + t2" / "rel_sum r1 r2"
```

is the combined quotient type. You can then define the two quotients as projections:

```
lift_definition Abs1 :: "t1 ⇒ q" is "Inl" .
lift_definition Abs2 :: "t2 ⇒ q" is "Inr" .

typedef q1 = "range Abs1" by blast
typedef q2 = "range Abs2" by blast
```

With `setup_lifting`, you can register `q1` and `q2` with the lifting package, too. Then, you get decent automation for lifting proofs and definitions. You just have to do two lifting steps (first from `t1 + t2` to `q` and then from `q` to `q1` or `q2`) for definitions and two unlifting steps for proofs.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was after.  Incidentally, this trick could be perhaps added to the Isabelle documentation.